# LINQ query with WHERE clause having dynamic table name

Tags: c#, linq

I currently have one table that holds data for which rows are being synchronized by clients. And I use it something like this:

```
var syncRows = context.SynchronizingRows.Where(r => r.ClientId == clientId).Select(r => r.RowId);
return context.Customers.Where(c => syncRows.Contains(c.Id)).ToList();
// I have lots of tables to return, but the syncRows statement is always the same 
// (my Id's are GUID's, so they don't overlap)
```

I now want to split that table and create a seperate table for each client. The problem is, I can't figure out how to specify a table dynamically from a string.

I could use *ExecuteQuery* and write the entire query by hand:

```
return context.ExecuteQuery<Customer>("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE Id IN (SELECT ...);");
```

But this way I lose all static typing, Intellisense, etc. Basically a maintenance nightmare.

Because all the sync tables have the exact same definition - `CREATE TABLE Test1 (RowId [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL);` - I would ideally like to use this pseudo code:

```
public Interface ISync // can be a class as well...
{
   Guid RowId { get; set; }
}

IQueryable<ISync> syncRows = context.GetTable<ISync>("Test1");
return context.Customers.Where(...).ToList();
```

The idea being that I specify the table name *Test1* and the type of data and everything else just works like before.

**My question is - how to achieve this?**

NB!
1) You can't cheat by doing `var syncRows = context.ExecuteQuery<ISync>("SELECT * FROM Test1");` - because this would destroy the SQL query for selecting Customers. (`Contains()` has a limit of 2100 items if you pass in values from c# side, so the *Contains* part must be integrated into the SQL query itself as an SQL statement - meaning `syncRows` has to be an `IQueryable`)

2) [Dynamic LINQ Library](http://dynamiclinq.azurewebsites.net/) does not work - `context.Customers.Where("Id IN (SELECT ...)")` - throws an exception complaining it can't handle *SELECT*. (Although I wouldn't mind writing only the Where statement by hand)

3) No LINQ-To-Entities!! Only **LINQ-To-SQL**!

4) I pondered about the idea of selecting `syncRows` like in point 1 and passing them in via Table-Valued Parameters, but:
a) Alas - LINQ to SQL does not support TVP's
b) Not even with stored procedures
c) Even if I could (say as an XML parameter), passing in an entire list of Id's from c# side to SQL side 50+ times (lots of tables to sync) would probably be detremental to peformance. Also I would have to write each stored procedure by hand for each table - again no static typing, no Intellisense...

Using c#, .NET 4.5, SQL 2014

Comment: @Marco why all the restrictions a single table with a filter for each customer. Development and maintenance are more straightforward.

Comment: @peter - the reason why I wan't to get away from that single table is, because SQL is so stupid it can't handle multiple inserts/selects in a single table. It will deadlock (even with no indexes). Instead of fighting a lost cause, I want to create a seperate table for each client. Then I have no lock contention and better parallel performance. Just need to figure out how to get LINQ to accept a table name dynamically...